# Where to put resource in java project and how to read from resource

Tags: java

I am trying to read resources from my java project, I have placed properties files in resource/properties/name.properties. Following is the code what I return so far,want to read from relative path.

```
public void loadResource()
{
    Properties config = new Properties();
    final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println("current dir = " + dir);
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(dir+"resource/properties/name.properties"); 
    try
    {
        config.load(in);
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
```

Comment: how do i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

**Resources are always loaded from classpath.**

If you specify relative path, then relative to the class, otherwise absolute on the classpath (not disk).

Your program is incorrect, you should use:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/properties/name.properties");
```